# AngularJS Pagination - Get Current Page and Pass to Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am implementing server-side sorting and pagination, and I need to pass the current page that the user is on so that if they sort and are on a page different than the first page (ex. sort by "least votes" on page 5 does not show the resorted results from page 1 on page 5 but shows the resorted results that should be on page 5). Basically, I need in place sorting but can't figure out how to get the current page.

Server side paging is working without issue, and I believe I am missing something simple here.

HTML (please note that I am using this custom directive: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)

```
<tr dir-paginate="article in articles | itemsPerPage:articlesPerPage" total-items="totalArticles" current-page="currentPage">

<td>
    <div class="col-md-1 voting well">
        <div class="votingButton" ng-click="upVote(articlevote);">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="badge badge-inverse">
            <div>{{article.articlevotes}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="votingButton" ng-click="downVote(articlevote);">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td>{{article.articletitle}}</td>
<td>{{article.articlecategoryid}}</td>
<td><a ng-href="#article/{{article.id}}/{{article.articlelink}}">{{article.articletitle}}</a></td>
</tr>
                </table>
<dir-pagination-controls on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

Controller

```
$scope.articles = [];
$scope.totalArticles = 0;
$scope.articlesPerPage = 10; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page
$scope.currentPage = 1;


   // sort options
$scope.sortoptions = [
{
    label: 'Most Votes',
    value: 'articlevotes desc',
},
{
    label: 'Least Votes',
    value: 'articlevotes asc',
}
];

var sortBy = $scope.sortoptions[0].value;
var currPage = $scope.currentPage; // Get current page
console.log(currPage);

// Initial page load
getResultsPage(1, sortBy);

$scope.update = function (articleSortOrder) {
    // get value of sort and log it
    console.log(articleSortOrder.value); 
    sortBy = articleSortOrder.value;

    // log current page and pass as parameter
    console.log(currPage);
    getResultsPage(currPage, sortBy); // need to make dynamic so it gets current page
}

$scope.pageChanged = function (newPage) {
    getResultsPage(newPage, sortBy);
};

function getResultsPage(pageNumber, sortorder) {

    // currently skipping by page number * articles per page
    pfcArticles.query({ $skip: (pageNumber - 1) * $scope.articlesPerPage, $top: $scope.articlesPerPage, $orderby: sortorder, $inlinecount: 'allpages' }, function (data) {
        $scope.articles = data.results;
        $scope.totalArticles = data.count; // Can change to hard number to reduce total items instead of LimitTo
    });
}
```

Comment: If I console log the $scope.currentPage, it is only returning the number 1. I have tried the code listed in some paging plunks, and the plunker returns the page numbers correctly but mine doesn't.

Comment: I don't see the `dir-paginate` and `dir-pagination-controls` directives in your view code. Could you update the question to show them?

Comment: Added, it appears that the currentPage is not being passed. I spun up an example of the default angularUI pagination but appeared to have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning:

```
var currPage = $scope.currentPage;
```

So `currPage` is set to `1` as your controller is instantiated, and is then never changed. So when you reference `currPage` later in the controller, it remains `1`.

You should instead directly reference the `$scope.currentPage` value, which will get updated by the pagination directive.

So try changing the "update" method to this:

```
$scope.update = function (articleSortOrder) {
    sortBy = articleSortOrder.value;
    getResultsPage($scope.currentPage, sortBy);
}
```

This should pass the correct current page value to your service.

Comment: I've been trying that as it should work... and that is where things are weird. It doesn't pass. Maybe its related to calling my controllers as part of app.js instead of in the page? the pageChanged function works with the newPage variable representing the correct page number.

Comment: Just found the issue. I have a controller overlap because a div got deleted that closed that div. Count this as coding while tired! Thanks @Michael Bromley